# Is there a calculus of non-commutative variables?

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

I know the integral calculus for commuting variables (which is just normal calculus).

And there is an  Grassman integral calculus for anti-commuting variables. (Variables where $\theta_1 \theta_2 = - \theta_2\theta_1$ ).

Is there a calculus for general variables that in general satisfy:

$$x y\neq y x$$

Perhaps it would be a calculus of matrices where $x$ and $y$ are general matrices?

Comment: There is calculus for general Banach Algebras, especially in the sense that you can talk about Differential Equations in Banach Algebras. For instance, there is a Picard-Lindelof Theorem for real Banach spaces that you can use to get a version of the exponential function in a general Banach algebra.

Comment: Fields medalist Alain Connes has been developing _noncommutative geometry_. See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.00132.pdf for  "noncommutative differential calculus or “quantized” calculus"